# Get the parent tag for cursor position in CKEditor 4

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, wysiwyg

This seems like something simple to do but I am unable to find the answer I need from the docs.

I have created a function which inserts blockquote/cite HTML, however I need to wrap this in an IF statement to detect whether it is already inside a blockquote element and not include the  tag if so

What I am trying to do is get the parent tag of the current cursor position:

```
    exec : function( editor ){                          
        alert( editor.getParent() ); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to check whether caret is already inside `blockquote`, then you should use:

```
editor.elementPath().contains( 'blockquote' )
```

This will look for `blockquote` element in the entire path - not only in the last node (which does not even have to be an element).

See docs for [`CKEDITOR.dom.elementPath`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.dom.elementPath).

Comment: Thanks - makes sense but doesn't seem to work for me?

`if (editor.elementPath().contains( 'blockquote' ))
    {
     editor.insertHtml( '<p>This is your quote - please edit this.</p><cite>Mr. Author, London</cite>' );
    }
    else
    {
     editor.insertHtml( '<blockquote><p>This is your quote - please edit this.</p><cite>Mr. Author, London</cite></blockquote>' );
    }`

Getting 'elementPath' is not a function. Without the function brackets the value is undefined.

Comment: Are you sure you're using CKEditor 4.x?

Answer (score 0):

```
editor.getSelection().getStartElement()
```

**Documentation:**

[CKEDITOR.dom.document.getSelection()](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_dom_document.html#method-getSelection)

[CKEDITOR.dom.selection.getStartElement()](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_dom_selection.html#method-getStartElement)